# getNodeValue() Problem?

Tags: java, android, xml

I don't know why my if statement is not firing. I see in the logs that LoginStatus shows SUCCESS

```
LoginStatus = nameElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();

System.out.println("status = *" + LoginStatus + "*");    

if(LoginStatus == "SUCCESS"){

     String FILENAME = "UserData.xml";
     FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     fos.write(response.getBytes());
     fos.close();
     System.out.println("File Created");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing a `String` correctly.  Use `equals` rather than the equality operator:

```
if("SUCCESS".equals(LoginStatus)){
```

p.s. Java convention is for variables to start with a lowercase letter, so `loginStatus`